# Linq Objects Group By & Sum

Tags: c#, linq, dataset, sum

I have a datatable with a column "No" and "Total" column. I'd like to bring back the sum of the "Total" column for each "No". I've tried the below, but I'm getting several errors as I'm struggling with the syntax.

```
var Values =
        (from data in DtSet.Tables["tblDetails"].AsEnumerable()
         group data by data.Field<"No">
         select new
         {
             name_1 = data.Field<double>("No"),
             name_2 = data.Field<double>("Total"),
         }
         );
```

Comment: `name_1` and `name_2` sound like terrible names. Why don't you name them `No` and `TotalSum`, or something like that?

Comment: a good example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386991.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will give you sum of `Total` fields in `name_2` property, and grouping `No` in `name_1` property (I think you need better naming here)

```
var Values = from row in DtSet.Tables["tblDetails"].AsEnumerable()
             group row by row.Field<double>("No") into g
             select new
             {
                 name_1 = g.Key,
                 name_2 = g.Sum(r => r.Field<double>("Total"))
             };
```

Consider about names `No` and `TotalSum` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on the naming conventions. Your code works - thank you. How would I go about bring through another column that didn't need summing, for example, name_3 would be the field "AccountNo"...?

Comment: @user1936588 do all rows with same `No` value have same `AccountNo`? If yes, then you can include `AccountNo` into grouping key. Otherwise you will have list of account numbers like this `Accounts = g.Select(r => r.Field<string>("AccountNo").ToList()`

Answer (score 1):

You start using linq, but good old `DataTable` has it's [own way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute%28v=VS.80%29.aspx):

```
var total = DtSet.Tables["tblDetails"].Compute("sum(Total)", "No = x");
```

I have to leave it with the `x` in it, because I don't know the values of the "No" column. The part `"No = x"` is a filter. If it is null or an empty string all rows will be used in the computation.

Comment: So you have to do this for each `No`? In that case, I think this is worse than LINQ in every way.

Comment: @svick No, it does the computation for the whole table at once.

Comment: But the second part is filter, no? So if I want to calculate the sum of totals for each `No` (which the question asks for), I have to execute this for each `No`. E.g., if the values of `No` were 1,2,…1000, then I would have to execute it with `No=1`,`No=2`,…,`No=1000`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @svick Ah, sorry, I see what you mean now. The filter can be null or an empty string to use all rows. Good you made me add this.