# Please suggest a linq query for my requirement

Tags: linq

Can anyone suggest a linq query  for the below requirement.

There is a  Checkbox on the form..when we click on it...As per the below datatable  it has to be grouped according to `ItemCode`,`Sum(SoldQty)`, `StockInHand`,`LatestRecordValueOfSales`, `Amount`, `Description`.

You can't group. the following columns

1. `solddate` - show the latest sold date
2. `department`
3. `category`

---

```
ItemCode Description UOM SoldQty Stock in Hand SellPrice Amount
--------------------------------------------------------------- 

100 Paracetamol 200MG UOM1 5 -5 3 8 0 100 1/21/2013 MEAT INDIAN BEAF 
100 Paracetamol 200MG UOM1 5 -5 3 8 0 100 1/21/2013 MEAT INDIAN BEAF 
200 frozen meat Kilograms 0.005 88.19 4 4.01 0 200 1/21/2013 OTHERS INDIAN BEAF 
200 frozen meat Kilograms 0.044 88.19 4 4.04 0 200 1/21/2013 OTHERS INDIAN BEAF 
100 Paracetamol 200MG UOM1 5 -5 3 8 0 100 1/22/2013 MEAT INDIAN BEAF 
200 frozen meat Kilograms 0.054 88.19 4 4.05 0 200 1/22/2013 OTHERS INDIAN BEAF 
200 frozen meat Kilograms 0.055 88.19 4 4.06 0 200 1/22/2013 OTHERS INDIAN BEAF
========================================================================
```

Comment: For more clear data ...can you please go through this link http://forums.asp.net/t/1877192.aspx/1?suggest+a+linq+query+for+my+requirement+

Answer (score 0):

**General query**

```
var resQuery = from i in someQueryable
              group i by new {i.groupProperty1, i.groupProperty2} into g
                          select new
                          {
                              Property1 = g.Key.Property1,
                              Property2 = g.Key.Property2
                              Total = g.Sum(p => p.SumProperty),
                              /// other properties
                          };
```

For your example data it could be like:

```
var resQuery = from i in dbContext.Items
              group i by new{ i.ItemCode, i.Description, i.UOM} into g
                          select new
                          {
                              ItemCode = g.Key.ItemCode,
                              TotalSold = g.Sum(p => p.SoldQty),
                              Description = g.Key.Description,
                              UOM =g.Key.UOM
                              /// other properties
                          };
```

Try example on Ideone: http://ideone.com/xXwgoG

Similar questions asked on SO many times:

- [Linq Objects Group By & Sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465578/linq-objects-group-by-sum)
- [LINQ Lambda Group By with Sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970070/linq-lambda-group-by-with-sum)
- [Multiple group by and Sum LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541030/multiple-group-by-and-sum-linq)

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply. It is working partially... how to get the other string columns like Description , UOM etc

Comment: Just the same way as you get `ItemCode` (suggesting that those are the properties of `Item`), like in my updated answer. When the query is executed (e.g. `resQuery.ToList()`, it will return `List` of anonymous objects (generated by compiler) with properties you have specified.

Comment: Hi Mipe34,

I am almost done..only error is that when i am doing the Sum for Soldqty it is doing twice.

I mean if
 
ItemCode SoldQty
 100      2
 100      1

So the sum should be 3..but I am getting 6.Other than that no problem thanks.

Comment: I have created for you working example on Ideone: http://ideone.com/xXwgoG and corrected syntax in my answer. PS. You don't need to thank me, just mark it as answered if my answer helped you ;-)

Comment: Hi...The first row data for Sum(SoldQty) and Sum(Amount) is getting doubled while for other rows it is fine

Comment: Hi I have posted my code in another forum..below is the link..as i am new to this forum I am not able to post my code today http://forums.asp.net/p/1877192/5279399.aspx/1?Re+suggest+a+linq+query+for+my+requirement+

Answer (score 0):

Below is my code and it works fine but only for the first row the soldqty and Amount values are getting doubled.while other rows data is fine.I am not able to understand why only the first row data Sum(SoldQty) is getting doubled.

```
decimal? SoldQty, stockinhand,SellPrice,Amount,CostPrice;
 string ItemCode, Description,UOM,BarCode,SoldDate,Department,Category,User;
  var resQuery = from row in dtFilter.AsEnumerable()
group row by row.Field<string>("Item Code") into g
 select dtFilter.LoadDataRow(new object[]
 {
 ItemCode=g.Key,
 Description=g.Select(r=>r.Field<string>("Description")).First<string>(),
 UOM=g.Select(r=>r.Field<string>("UOM")).First<string>(),  
 SoldQty = g.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal?>("Sold Qty")).Value,
 stockinhand=g.Select(r=>r.Field<decimal?>("Stock in Hand")).First<decimal?>(),
 SellPrice=g.Select(r=>r.Field<decimal?>("Sell Price")).First<decimal?>(),
 Amount = g.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal?>("Amount")).Value,
 CostPrice = g.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal?>("Cost Price")).Value,
 BarCode=g.Select(r=>r.Field<string>("Barcode")).First<string>(),
 SoldDate=g.Select(r=>r.Field<string>("SoldDate")).Last<string>(),
 Department=g.Select(r=>r.Field<string>("Department")).First<string>(),
 Category=g.Select(r=>r.Field<string>("Category")).First<string>(),
 User=g.Select(r=>r.Field<string>("User")).First<string>(),  }, false);
```

Comment: You should not put extension of your question as answer. Please extend your question with code from this answer and then delete this post.